# Total SUM Input Form Value With Laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a form in Laravel (only) with 3 fields: `title, price, quantity` , the name of the page is named 'create.blade.php'. 
[image]

**My first problem** is that when I enter the 3 values, nothing happening! The page create.blade.php is stuck ! I don't have error message

[image]

**my second problem** is to get the amount total on my page 'index.blade.php'

In my table **products** I have this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->double('price');
            $table->double('total')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

In my **productController** I have this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.products.index', compact('products'))
                  ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1)-1)*5);
    }


    public function create()
    {

        $products = Product::all();
        return view('admin.products.create', compact('products'));
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required',
                'quantity' => 'required',
                'price' => 'required',
                'total' => 'required'
        ]);

        Product::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('products.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');
    }
```

In my **Model Product**

```
 protected  $fillable = ['title', 'quantity', 'price', 'total']; 

    public function setTotalAttribute()
    {
        $this->attributes['total'] = $this->quantity * $this->price;
    }

    public function getTotalAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
```

And in my **create.blade.php** I have this:

```
 <form class="panel-body" action="{{route('products.store')}}" method="POST" novalidate>
              @csrf
              <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('title') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="{{ old('title')}}"/>
                {!! $errors->first('title', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('quantity') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Quantity</label>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control" value="{{ old('quantity')}}"/>
                {!! $errors->first('quantity', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
              </fieldset>

              <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('price') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="form-group-input-1">Price</label>
                <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" value="{{ old('price')}}"/>
                {!! $errors->first('price', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
              </fieldset>

              <a href="{{route('products.index')}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Back</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">OK</button>

            </form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('/products', 'ProductController');
```

File **index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($products as $product)
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$product->title}}</td>
                   <td> {{$product->quantity}}</td>
                   <td> {{$product->price}}</td>
                   <td> {{$product->total}}</td>
                   <td>
                     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('products.destroy', $product) }} ">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{route('products.edit',$product->id)}}">Editer</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Deleter</button>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

If I already know how to solve my first problem about the create.blade.php, I am happy.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Edit: 
[image]

I don't get the amount total...

Comment: Show us your routes, please!

Comment: @Lucas Piazzi: Hello Piazzi, ^^ I have edited my message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem:**

In your `productController` you are validating that `'total' => 'required'` but in your `create.blade.php` file you are not submitting anything regarding `total`. As a result, the validation is returning error but you are not even showing it. So, you are thinking that the form is stuck though it's not. Actually it's redirecting back with validation error of `total` filed is required.

**Second problem**

I am not 100% sure about this solution but you can try the mutator below. model.

```
public function setTotalAttribute()
{
    $this->attributes['total'] = $this->attributes['quantity'] * $this->attributes['price'];
}
```

By the way you don't need the unnecessary `getTotalAttribute` method in your

**From comments**

Seems like you are struggling with Eloquent's mutator. So, let's remove the mutator `setTotalAttribute` method and accessor from model and in controller

replace following line:

`Product::create($request->all());`

by the following lines:

```
$data = $request->all(); 
$data['total'] = $request->price * $request->quantity; 
Product::create($data);
```

Now check if it works.

Comment: thank you my first problem is solve. But now, how I can get the total please? My model Product is not correct ???

Comment: Updated the answer, try it.

Comment: @Imrar: Thank you Imran, in my index.blade.php I have put this `<td> {{$product->setTotalAttribute->total}}</td>` but I have an error message `App\Product::setTotalAttribute must return a relationship instance.` I am really stuck.... :-(

Comment: In your blade you need to print it like `{{$product->total}}` that's it

Comment: @Imrane, I have tried several times but without success. Perhaps it's a formatting issue ?

Comment: When you use `{{$product->total}}`, are you getting any error? what is the formatting issue you talking about? please clarify.

Comment: when I use `{{$product->total}}` my column the amount total stays empty. I don't have error message. I think my model is not works?

Comment: I have edited my first message, there is a third image. You see, the column total is empty.

Comment: The column `total` is empty because there is `null` in your database. So, when you create the product there was problem with the `setTotalAttribute()` method. Create another product and see if works or not.

Comment: Indeed, it's `null`... I have tried several times... the function `setTotalAttribute()` must be called in the controller?

Comment: Seems like you are struggling with Eloquent's mutator. So, let's remove  the `setTotalAttribute` method from model. and in controller `$data = $request->all();  $data['total'] = $request->price * $request->quantity; Product::create($data);`

Comment: Updated the answer containing the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you a lot Imran it's OK :-) Barraka Allah fik akhi... Sorry for the delay.